# Loop scraping until number VBA Excel Getelementby

Tags: excel, getelementsbytagname, vba

I am scraping this page at work, it is after a log-in but I will try to explain the situation as good as I can

I got a page where I want to get the number that appears after a random amount of time have passed (Depending on the stat of our server, computer etc) It is not scraping until IE.readystat <> 4 but the numbers do still not always appear until a little bit later then that

```
Sent = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(25).innertext
Sheet4.Range("D" & i).Value = Sent
```

There are 3 things I get back are:

1 Run Time Error: 91

2 The text "Loading..."

3 12,403 (The number that I am looking for)

I was wondering if there is anyone out there that know if I can loop the scraping until I actually get a number back and then move on to the next task? Without stopping at the "Run time error:91" (Just get excel to ignore that message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic JSON (or other) content can really foul up retrieving a web page as both `ie.Busy` and `ie.ReadyState` appear to have completed the page delivery but the desired content is yet to arrive. I've been fighting a losing battle with one of these sites on and off for a while now and it doesn't help that the web designers have the professional competency bar set pretty low. Here is what I'm currently using, roughly translated for your purposes.

```
 Dim url as String
 url = "https://www.mydomain.com"
 ie.Navigate2 url, (navNoHistory + navNoReadFromCache + navNoWriteToCache)  ' &H2 + &H4 + &H8
 Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop   ' READYSTATE_COMPLETE is 4
 Do While ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span").length < 26: DoEvents: Loop
 Sent = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("span")(25).innertext
 Sheet4.Range("D" & i).Value = Sent
```

You were looking for the 26th `<span>` element so if the page is never going to send across at least 26 <span>'s then you will be in a forever loop. There are ways to a) eventually give up or b) send an `ie.Refresh` for another attempt. If you break the loop into separate code lines, you could test against an ultimate time out.

Testing the `.style.visible` property of the *Loading...* text is another method. Unfortunately, I cannot be more specific without seeing at least a portion of that HTML code.

Comment: Yeap you are a boss man! Thanks, it turnes out that there are 36 spans that get created directly and then an extra 20 coming afterwards so changed the 26 to 50 and I works like a dream!!!!! I really like the way this was solved as well. I has not failed any of my sample tests! Thank you @Jeeped!